# Delete the last two characters from a href attribute on a list of links

Tags: javascript, list, href

I need to delete the last two characters from a href on a list of links when the page loads. I know it should be something easy but I'm getting struggle with that.

I have these links:

```
<a href="#my-anchor-link-2" class="table-contents-link"></a>
<a href="#my-anchor-link-3" class="table-contents-link"></a>
<a href="#my-anchor-link-4" class="table-contents-link"></a>
```

I need to remove the "-#" at the end of each links

I started with something like this:

```
const t = document.getElementsByClassName('table-contents-link').href.substr(-2);
```

I'm not sure how to continue.

Comment: What does `getElementsByClassName` return?

Comment: `.getElementsByClassName(...)` returns an array of elements. You need to loop thru the array of elements first

Comment: There is no `-#` at the end of each link provided in your code. Can you clarify?

Comment: I was meaning that "-#" represents the number of each link at the end I put # because there is no specific amount of number, some times the list can be 3 links, and another time can be 6 links. But in any case, I need to delete the las two characters of each link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should select all element's you need, so we used `document.querySelectorAll` then we should loop over the result to remove the last 2 characters from the string in `href` Attribute

```js
let links = document.querySelectorAll(".table-contents-link");
links.forEach((link) => {
    link.setAttribute('href', link.getAttribute('href').slice(0, -2))
})
```

```html
<a href="google.com" class="table-contents-link">Link 1</a>
<a href="stackoverflow.com" class="table-contents-link">Link 2</a>
<a href="github.com" class="table-contents-link">Link 3</a>
```